# Questions about pages 11-12 of Janusz's "Algebraic Number Fields"

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I have questions regarding multiple steps in the proofs on these pages.

1. **[Resolved in the comments]** In the proof of Corollary $3.10$, where $B$ is a noetherian ring whose every prime ideal is maximal and $\mathfrak{P_1},\dots,\mathfrak{P_n}$ are primes such that $\mathfrak{P_1}^{a_1}\cdots\mathfrak{P_n}^{a_n}=0$, he states that $\mathfrak{P_i}/\mathfrak{P_i}^{a_i}$ is the only prime ideal of $B/\mathfrak{P_i}^{a_i}$. Why is this so? I can see that it is indeed a prime and that $\mathfrak{P_i}^{a_i}$ is contained in no other $\mathfrak{P_j}$, but why is it not possible for there to exist some other prime $\mathfrak{R}$ containing $\mathfrak{P_i}^{a_i}$?
2. **[Resolved]** In Lemma $3.11$, it is shown that for $\mathfrak{p}$ maximal, $R/\mathfrak{p}^a\cong R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$. The first line of the proof states that the map $f(r+\mathfrak{p}^a)=r+\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$ is injective. Why? If $r\in\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$, then $r=\frac bc$, where $b\in\mathfrak{p}^a$ and $c\notin\mathfrak{p}$, then $rc\in\mathfrak{p}^a\subset\mathfrak{p}$ and hence $r\in\mathfrak{p}$, but why does it follow that $r\in\mathfrak{p}^a$? **[Solution]**: $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^a$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R/\mathfrak{p}^a$, because if $\mathfrak{m}$ is a maximal ideal containing $\mathfrak{p}^a$, then (being prime) it must contain $\mathfrak{p}$, which is maximal, hence $\mathfrak{m}=\mathfrak{p}$. That $c\notin\mathfrak{p}$ implies $\overline{c}\notin\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^a$, which being the unique maximal ideal implies $\overline{c}$ is a unit of $R/\mathfrak{p}^a$, therefore $rc\in\mathfrak{p}^a\implies\overline{r}\,\overline{c}=0\implies\overline{r}=0\implies r\in\mathfrak{p}^a$.
3. Corollary $3.12$ applies the foregoing lemma to show that for a Dedekind domain $R$ and prime $\mathfrak{p}$, every ideal of $R/\mathfrak{p}^a$ is a power of $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^a$. The proof replaces $R/\mathfrak{p}^a$ by $R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$ and refers to the fact that $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a DVR. I've filled in the blanks as follows: $R_\mathfrak{p}$ is a DVR and $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}$ is the unique prime, so the ideals containing $\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}=(\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p})^a$ are $(\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p})^k$ for $k\leq a$. From this follows that the ideals of  $R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$ are of the form $(\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p})^k/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}=(\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p})^k$ (since $I^n/J=(I/J)^n$, presumably), i.e. powers of $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$. Under the isomorphism $f$ from question $2)$, the ideal $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^a$ is mapped injectively into $\mathfrak{p}R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$. If $\frac rs+\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$ is a typical element of the latter, where $r\in\mathfrak{p}$ and $s\notin\mathfrak{p}$, we get that $(s)$ and $\mathfrak{p}^a$ are comaximal, so $cs+q=1$ for some $c$ and $q\in\mathfrak{p}^a$, so $f(rc+\mathfrak{p}^a)=\frac rs+\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$ and $rc\in\mathfrak{p}$, i.e. the map is surjective and the two ideals correspond under $f$. Therefore, knowing how the ideals of $R_\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^aR_\mathfrak{p}$ look, we know the ideals of $R/\mathfrak{p}^a$ are powers of $\mathfrak{p}/\mathfrak{p}^a$. Is this correct?
4. Next is this proof.
   [image]
   From "Let $B'$...'' on, why are the ideals of $B'$ images of $\mathfrak{p}_1^{c_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{c_n}$ for $c_i\leq b_i$? I tried to fill in the blanks as follows: by CRT the ideals of $B'$ correspond to direct sums of ideals of $B/\mathfrak{p}_i^{b_i}$, which by the lemma referred to in question $2)$ (even though the text refers to something else) are of the form $\mathfrak{p}_i^{c_i}/\mathfrak{p}_i^{b_i}$ with $c_i\leq b_i$. Next, I was thinking that generally in the context of the CRT if $J_k\supset I_k$, then the ideal $\bigoplus_kJ_k/I_k$ in $\bigoplus_kR/I_k$ corresponds to the ideal $J_1\cdots J_n/I_1\cdots I_n$ of $R/I_1\cdots I_n$. This seems to be true, so ideals of $B'$ must be of the form $\mathfrak{p}_1^{c_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{c_n}/\mathfrak{p}_1^{b_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{b_n}$ and thus images of some $\mathfrak{p}_1^{c_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{c_n}$. Is this correct? The equality $\mathfrak{A}=\mathfrak{p}_1^{c_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{c_n}$ then follows by the correspondence theorem because both are ideals containing $\mathfrak{p}_1^{b_1}\cdots\mathfrak{p}_n^{b_n}$.
5. For the uniqueness of the $a_i$, I've succeeded in showing $\mathfrak{A}R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}=\mathfrak{p}_i^{a_i}R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$, I would like to check if the technicalities of the previous line of the book proof are correct. Let $R_i:=R_{\mathfrak{p}_i}$, $\pi_i$ the unique prime of $R_i$, then $(\pi_i)/(\pi_i^{a_i})$ is the unique maximal ideal of $R_i/(\pi_i^{a_i})$. The least power annihilating this ideal is the least power $k$ such that $\pi_i^k$ belongs to $(\pi_i^{a_i})$, which is clearly $a_i$. Correct?
   [image]

Comment: Every element of $I/I^n$ is nilpotent in $R/I^n$.

So any prime ideal of $R/I^n$ contains $I/I^n$.

If $I$ is maximal then $I/I^n$ will be the only prime ideal of $R/I^n$.

Comment: @reuns thanks, that clears 1) up. I didn't think to apply the nilradical to this, thought it would be more elementary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Question $1)$ was answered in the comments, the answer to question $2)$ I found elsewhere, and the rest are more or less clear.